# How to add a custom field to an array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

I have an array:

```
const array = ["en-US", "en-GB", "en-AU"] as const;
```

And I would like to add to this array a field `default` in order to do something like:

```
array.default;
```

Instead of

```
array[0];
```

Constraints: Not loosing the property of an array and be able to still use `find` and all other things propers to arrays. I also need the correct typing.

Comment: I think you can use `interface CustomArray<T>`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxJAzw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create an object that combines two objects by copying the properties of one to another.

In the example below a function is created that adds a *default* field to an object. *Object.assign* is passed the source object and an object literal with a property that is set a value at the first index.  The returned value *is* the original source with the new field.

```
function addDefault<T extends readonly unknown[]>(src: T): T & { default: T[0] } {
  return Object.assign(src, { default: src[0] });
}
const array = addDefault(["en-US", "en-GB", "en-AU"] as const);
console.log(array.default); // en-US
```

This will work fine as long as you're working with immutable types as in your example.  However, if you wanted a more flexible version that works with mutable array, and the value at index 0 changes, then *default* will still be the original value at 0.  The only way to get the updated value is to use a method instead instead of a field.

The example below will work on more types, but the *default* field has been changed to a method.

```
function addDefault<T extends { [x: number]: unknown }>(src: T): T & { default: T[0] } {
  return Object.assign(src, { default() => src[0] );
}
const array = addDefault(["en-US", "en-GB", "en-AU"]);
array[0] = "fr-FR";
console.log(array.default()); // fr-FR
```

Comment: Btw would you have any idea why this typing doesn't work ? https://tsplay.dev/wO17Em It's the same thing basically. Line 121.

Comment: could you check the link above please